# JS: Not sure the use of static for functions in classes

Tags: javascript

I am trying to understand the use of `static` before a function within a class.  These seems to behave the same when called but what does having a static function allow for?

```
class Car {
   constructor(type) {
      this.type = type;
   }

   static getCar1() {
       return this.type;
   }
   getCar2() {
       return this.type;
   }
}
```

Comment: When you invoke `static` method you can use Class name instead of Instance name.

Comment: Also, `this` on a static method refers to the class itself, not the object.

Comment: ahh I see.  That wouldn't work if the `static` method returns a property set in the constructor like I have above, right?

Comment: Yeah, exactly. `static` methods can't access those values, since you can only call them  from the class, not from the object, as mentioned before and on the accepted answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Referencing the MDN

> The static keyword defines a static method or property for a class. Neither static methods nor static properties can be called on instances of the class. Instead, they're called on the class itself. Static methods are often utility functions, such as functions to create or clone objects, whereas static properties are useful for caches, fixed-configuration, or any other data you don't need to be replicated across instances.

You call the static method not on your instances of a class you call it on the class itself.

```js
class ClassWithStaticMethod {
  
  
  
  static staticProperty = 'someValue';
  static staticMethod() {
    return 'static method has been called.';
  }
}

console.log(ClassWithStaticMethod.staticProperty);
// output: "someValue"
console.log(ClassWithStaticMethod.staticMethod());
// output: "static method has been called."
```

When you try to call it on an instance of the class

```js
class ClassWithStaticMethod {

  static staticProperty = 'someValue';
  static staticMethod() {
    return 'static method has been called.';
  }
}

c = new ClassWithStaticMethod();
// undefined
console.log(c.staticProperty);

// c.staticMethod is not a function
console.log(c.staticMethod());
```

Also note that this in static methods refers to the class.
As you can see in the example below.
So return this.type will not work in your static method

```js
class Car {
   constructor(type) {
      this.type = type;
   }

   static getCar1() {
       return this.type;
   }
   getCar2() {
       return this.type;
   }
   static getIt(){
      return this;
   }
   getIt(){
    return this;
   }
}

// returns the class
console.log(Car.getIt());

// returns the object with its property
c = new Car("Whatever");
console.log(c.getIt());
```

Answer (score 0):

The static function belongs the the class itself instead of an instance, so in your code `Car.getCar1()` is valid however `Car.getCar2()` is not. The getCar2() method can only be called on an instance ex:

```
C = new Car();
C.getCar2(); // Works

Car.getCar2(); //Doesn’t work because getCar2() isn’t static
```

Answer (score 0):

Static methods are not called on instances of the class. Instead, they are called in the class itself. They are usually utility functions, such as functions for creating or cloning objects.

In your example, to use the `getCar1()` method, you don't need an instance, just call the class and method

```
Car.getCar1()
```

To use `getCar2()` you need an instance

```
const car = new Car("Dodge")
car.getCar2()
```

Comment: Correct. But pass in a type. `const car = new Car("Dodge");`